# Объединить 2 строки в одну, сохранив упорядоченность

Tags: строки, ассемблер

Заданы 2 строки, в которых символы упорядочены по порядку уменьшения кода. Объединить их в одну строку, сохранив упорядоченность.
Мой код:

```html
 .386
.model flat,stdcall
 option  casemap:none
 
include \masm32\include\windows.inc
include \masm32\include\masm32.inc
include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc
include \masm32\macros\macros.asm
includelib \masm32\lib\masm32.lib
includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib
include \masm32\include\user32.inc 
includelib \masm32\lib\user32.lib

.data 
Caption db '1',0  
s1 db '654',0
s2 db '321',0
buffer db 256 dup(0)
format db "%d",0
string db 7 dup(?)
 
.code
jmp Start

Function:
lea esi, s1
lea edi, s2
lea ebx, buffer
xor eax, eax       ; eax=0
next:
mov al, [esi]
mov ah, [edi]
or  eax, eax
jz  printt         ; Обе строки закончились (al=0 и ah=0, значит и eax=0)
or  al, al         
jz  sm1            ; первая строка закончилась
or  ah, ah
jz  sm2            ; вторая строка закончилась
cmp al, ah
ja  sm1
sm2:
mov [ebx], al
inc esi
inc ebx
jmp next
sm1:
mov [ebx], ah
inc edi
inc ebx
jmp next
printt:
mov [ebx], al      ; на всякий случай пишем окончание строки в буфер (al=0)
ret

Output:
invoke wsprintf,addr buffer,addr format, ebx
;invoke MessageBoxA, 0, ADDR s1, ADDR Caption, 0 
 ;invoke MessageBoxA, 0, ADDR s2, ADDR Caption, 0 
;invoke MessageBoxA, 0, ADDR buffer, ADDR Caption, 0 
print   ADDR s1                      
print   ADDR s2                      
print   ADDR buffer                      
 ret

Start:
 call Function
 call Output
 
Exit:
   invoke ExitProcess, 0
   end Start
```

Исправьте, пожалуйста, что не так в коде.

Comment: А ассемблер что говорит ? он же наверняка кучу ошибок выдает, особенно учитывая что регистров eal, ecl, edl не существует

Comment: И вообще все как то сложно, забудьте про всякие lodsb, stosb и cmpsb. вы из за их использования все регистры по 100 раз перезагружаете. все гораздо проще `mov al, [esi] ; mov ah, [edi]; cmp al, ah; ... mov [ebx], al; inc esi` при условии, что в esi адрес первой строки, в edi второй, а в ebx строки куда копируем. и ситуацию с равенством можно обрабатывать вместе с одним из больше/меньше, т.е. копировать только один символ, все равно на следующем цикле скопируете второй

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю копирование должно выглядеть как то так (проверять не на чем):

```
    lea esi, s1
    lea edi, s2
    lea ebx, buffer
    xor eax, eax       ; eax=0
next:
    mov al, [esi]
    mov ah, [edi]
    or  eax, eax
    jz  printt         ; Обе строки закончились (al=0 и ah=0, значит и eax=0)
    or  al, al         
    jz  sm1            ; первая строка закончилась
    or  ah, ah
    jz  sm2            ; вторая строка закончилась
    cmp al, ah
    ja  sm1
sm2:
    mov [ebx], al
    inc esi
    inc ebx
    jmp next
sm1:
    mov [ebx], ah
    inc edi
    inc ebx
    jmp next
printt:
    mov [ebx], al      ; на всякий случай пишем окончание строки в буфер (al=0)
```

Пример на [ideone.com](https://ideone.com/mu5SjM)